# Show that $I_A+I_B$ and $|I_A−I_B|$ are uncorrelated.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $A$ and $B$ be independent events. Show that $I_A+I_B$ and
>   $|I_A−I_B|$ are uncorrelated. Are they independent?

I haven't quite figured out how to work with indicators and no matter how much I read about it in the book I still can't seem to grasp it. What does this actually mean and what am I supposed to do? I know that I somehow have to show that $\rho(A,B)=0$ but I have no idea how to compute the covariance,mean and variance of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: In general, $\mathbb{E}(I_A) = \mathbb{P}(A)$. Also, $| I_A - I_B |$ is the indicator function of the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$, which might help.

Comment: Actually you need to show $\rho(I_A,I_B)=0$.  Independence or not might come  for considering the joint possible values of $I_A+I_B, |I_A-I_B|$ in the four cases

Comment: No, you are not asked to compute $\rho(A,B)$, which is not even well defined because $A,B$ are events, not random variables.  However, you are given two random variables: $X=I_A+I_B$ and $Y=|I_A-I_B|$, and you are asked to show that $X,Y$ are uncorrelated, i.e. $\rho(X,Y) = 0$ or equivallently $Cov(X,Y)=0$.  Does this clarify the question enough for you to proceed?

Comment: To all the commenters, I'm having problem with the actual indicator functions. What are they? I know that they are used for events that only have two outcomes, but I have not fully grasped them. Any intuitive explanation for them?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to prove something that is false.

Let $\Omega$ be your probability space.  An event $A$ is a subset of $\Omega$ that belongs to its $\sigma$-algebra.  (Don't worry about what that last but means if you don't know what a $\sigma$-algebra is.)  $I_A$ is just a function on $\Omega$ with $I_A(\omega)=1$ for $\omega\in A$ and otherwise $I_A(\omega)=0$.  Thus, $E(I_A+I_B)=P(A)+P(B)$, $E(I_A+I_B)^2=P(A)+P(B)+2P(A~AND~B)$, $E(|I_A-I_B|^2)=E(|I_A-I_B|)=P(A~XOR~B)$, and also $E((I_A+I_B)|I_A-I_B|)=E(|I_A-I_B|)=P(A~XOR~B)$ since $I_A+I_B=1$ whenever $|I_A-I_B|\ne 0$.

Thus $Cov(I_A+I_B,|I_A-I_B|)=E((I_A+I_B)|I_A-I_B|)-E(I_A+I_B)E(|I_A-I_B|)=P(A~XOR~B)-(P(A)+P(B))P(A~XOR~B)$.

Thus, in order for $I_A+I_B$ and $|I_A-I_B|$ to be uncorrelated, you do not need $A$ and $B$ independent.  Rather, you need $P(A)+P(B)=1$ or $P(A~XOR~B)=0$. (The latter means $A=B$ (up to a set of measure zero--a comment I will omit from now on) or $A=B^c$)  However, even in that case they will not in general be independent, since we have already seen $I_A+I_B=1$ whenever $|I_A-I_B|\ne 0$.  Thus, for independence, you need $I_A+I_B$ or $|I_A-I_B|$ to be constant.  This only happens when $A=B$ or $A=B^c$, but not in the other cases with $P(A)+P(B)=1$.

Note that the only cases in which A and B are independent and the functions in the problem are uncorrelated are when A and B are independent with probabilities summing to 1 (probably the case the question-writer had in mind and he forgot to check whether his idea worked for other cases....ooops) and the degenerate cases where $P(A)=P(B)=0$ or $P(A)=P(B)=1$.